# PCSpim Text Window - What Does the Output Mean?

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32, pcspim

In PCSpim, when a program is executed, it displays in the Text Window a line for each instruction.

e.g. [0x00400028]  0x34020004  ori $2, $0, 4  ;13: li $v0, 4

That example loads 4 into the register $v0.

What does the ori $2, $0, 4 mean?

And is 0x34020004 just the same command, but in hexidecimal?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
[0x00400028] 0x34020004 ori $2, $0, 4 ;13: li $v0, 4
```

- `0x00400028` is the address where the instruction is located.
- `0x34020004` is the instruction word, i.e. the four bytes encoding the instruction.
- `ori $2, $0, 4` is the human-readable form of the instruction, which in this case sets `$2` (aka `$v0`) to 4.
- `li $v0, 4` is the instruction you typed in. Since `li` is a *pseudo-instruction*, it is translated by the assembler into one or more actual MIPS instructions (in this case `ori $2, $0, 4`).

Comment: and `ori` is bitwise OR, and it "ors" the zero from `$0` (called sometimes also `$zero`) with immediate constant `4`, which results into value `4`, and the result is stored into `$v0` (in pseudo C: `$v0 = $zero | 4;`)